# What is the difference between Twilio Elastic SIP Trunking, and Twilio SIP

Tags: twilio

Basic question here...for making calls in/out of Twilio, between PSTN numbers and SIP endpoints (e.g. PBX), it seems you could accomplish this using 1 of 2 methods:

1. Twilio SIP (using TwiML for translating between PSTN call and SIP call)
2. Elastic SIP Trunking

I'm wondering what the main differences in these methods are. It seems that with Twilio SIP you have use of TwiML-based applications, and with SIP Trunking you do not...is that the only difference?

Comment: The way I understand it, TwilioSIP is for use in Twiml type applications to terminate or originate a call from a known SIP endpoint or address. Elastic SIP Trunking is utilized when you have an existing application or appliance that needs to have origination and termination capabilities (think a PBX like Asterisk/Freeswitch) and Twilio will be that provider.

Comment: Thanks Matt...and that is basically what I am thinking. The way I see it, for basic orig/term, I think I can accomplish the same with both...but with TwilioSIP I'd have to provide some "plumbing" with TwiML instructions. In reality, having the TwiML in the call flow is not such a bad thing, since it gives me greater flexibility down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELASTIC SIP Trunking by Twilio is VoIP Carrier option with Global reach such that Load balancing / geographical redundancy and every other interconnect pain point is handled by Twilio and you can just focus on your application and not worry about interconnect partners and call termination in different countries.

I believe, after having built the partnerships to do the call terminations for applications that were making calls using [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), they decided to open the infrastructure to applications that dont necessarily have to be written over TwiML.